# how to use template string to add or remove class of a button on click of the same button react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a quiz app using React and I want to change the border color of a button from grey to green if answer is correct and to red if incorrect. I am using template literals and I want to apply a different className only onClick but I am not sure where to place this line of code. Currently, It shows the correct and wrong answers before being answered.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import "../index.css"


const QuestionSection = () => {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    const [showScore, setShowScore] = useState(false);
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
    const defaultBorder = "3px solid grey";
    const correctBorder = "3px solid green";
    const wrongBorder = "3px solid red";  
    const [border, setBorder] = useState(defaultBorder);
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const getQuestions = async () => {
            const questionsFromServer = await fetchQuestions()
            setQuestions(questionsFromServer)
        }

        getQuestions()
    }, [])
    //Fetch questions 
    const fetchQuestions = async () => {
        const res = await fetch ('http://localhost:5000/questions');
        const data = await res.json();
        
        return data 
    }
    
    
    const handleAnswerOptionClick = (correct) => {
        if (correct) {
            setScore(score + 1);
            setBorder(correctBorder);
            
        } else {
            setBorder(wrongBorder);
        }

        const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
        if (nextQuestion < questions.length) {
            setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
        } else {
            setShowScore(true);
        }
    };
  return (
    <questionSection>
    <div className='questionSection'>
            {showScore ? (
                <div className='score-section'>
                    You scored {score} out of {questions.length}
                </div>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <div className='question-section'>
                        <div className='question-count'>
                            <span>Question {currentQuestion + 1}</span>/{questions.length}
                        </div>
                        <div className='question-text'>{questions[currentQuestion]?.questionText}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='answer-section'>
                        {questions[currentQuestion]?.answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
                            <button 
                            //style = {`button ${answerOption.correct ? {correctBorder} : {wrongBorder}}`}
                            key = {answerOption.id} 
                            onClick={() => {
                            handleAnswerOptionClick(answerOption.correct, border);
                            
                            }}>
                            {answerOption.id} {answerOption.answerText}
                            </button>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    </questionSection>
  )
}

export default QuestionSection
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I spot a few problems here.

For one, you're setting `border` as a `className`, when it is defined as an object. Class names should be strings, and unless you have a CSS file not shown here it will have no effect. To apply objects as styles you need to use the `style` prop. [It's here in the React docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

The `border` property in CSS also takes 3 arguments, the `width`, `style`, and `color`. [See this link.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border_shorthand.asp) You're currently only passing one.

The state of your border is also confusing. It's instantiated as a string, `grey`, and then you are trying to update it to objects. It's unclear how you intend it to be read.

On that note, when you call `setBorder` in your button's `onClick`, you don't actually pass it a value to set to. [This article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-setstate/) explains `setState`.

Without a better look at the data you're fetching I'm not sure I can tell you exactly what else to implement to get it working, but here is a demo that I think should help illustrate a version of what you're trying to accomplish.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-firefly-m7vcj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive reply. I have decided to take a different approach and use template literals to update className depending on correct or incorrect answer. But now I have a different problem, as I want to only add the class on click. <div className='answer-section'>
      {questions[currentQuestion]?.answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
       <button 
       className = {`button ${answerOption.correct ? "correct" : "incorrect"}`}
       key = {answerOption.id} 
       onClick={() => {
       handleAnswerOptionClick(answerOption.correct);
       
       }}>

Comment: Following yip_yip advise, I amended the code in original post but I am still not able to wrap my head around it and achieve the desired result. Any help is welcomed.